# Don't get approval email if the previous step was approved via email

Tags: email, approval-process, approval-step

I have a strange issue. I have test order approval process, which has two steps. I have email notification on each step with an option to approve this step via email with key word "yes" or reject with key word "no". This is my approval process :
[image]
[image]
My issue that on the second step I don't receive approval email if the first step was approved with reply "yes" on email. But this step is approved with my reply! So reply to approval email works, but next email is't sent. If the first step is approved with a button, email for the second step is sent. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First check needs to be done at the Approval entry criteria, i.e.,

```
Status = InApproval
Order RecordType = Test
```

Hope in the first step the status is not being updated as **Approved**(or other than **InApproval**) which will restrict the record to enter this approval process again.

Secondly, the screen where we mention the criteria for each step(in this scenario, you need to check this section in first step):
[image]

We need to make sure that **go to next step** is selected other than **approve record/reject record**. So once a record passes through the first step, record when fulfils the **Entry criteria** at approval process would check for the FIRST STEP and if not fulfills(it wont coz it went through that step) should go through the next step as selected in the screenshot.

Comment: sorry but i think you didn't get me right. My approval process works really fine except that case when the first step is approved with reply 'yes' on approval email. In this cade the first step is approved and the second step is coming. But I don't get an approval email for the second step. Otherwise if i approve the first step with a button(not with reply on email), everything works correct and i get an email for the second step.